# Adding and deleting items from a sortable ordered list causes problems in numbering the items

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui, html-lists, jquery-ui-sortable

I have sortable ordered list with a few items. 
Each item in that list can be deleted and/or moved and I can dynamically add more new items.
All works fine as long as I do not add a new item and delete one of the existing one.

Example: 
I run the code and get a list

1. ABC
2. CDE
3. EFG
4. GHI
5. IJK

I delete "3.", so item "4." moves up and is now "3." on that list, while "5." ist now no "4."
So far so good.

If I add a new item it will be added at the end of the list as no "6.", "7." and so on.

But as soon as I delete or add any item I am running into problems with the numbering of the list items. I suddently have a list looking like that

e.g.
1. ABC
3. EFG
3. GHI
4. IJK

The numbering is no longer correct.
What can I do to prevent this from happening!?

-->  jsFiddle Demo:
http://tinyurl.com/kty73o6

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It works fine for me in fiddle.

Comment: Have you tried to add and delete items and then reorder?

Comment: hmm, I see it works in Firefox but not in IE ... 
Any idea?

Comment: Yes, I added, deleted, reodered. It also works in Opera. IE always causes the troubles... The only thing I can suggest is to look in "sortable" docs or in Internet to find out whether there are issues in "sortable" in IE or not. I mean problem can be inside "sortable".